# Generating html inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this jquery validation: http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/

It works perfectly but if I generate my code dynamically with javascript, if one of the input fails the data-validation, the error message will appear in all inputs.

Is there a way to fix this?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  inputs += '<div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">' + (i + 1) + '</span>' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for ' + result[i] + '"  name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName' + (i + 1) + '"' +
    'data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."\n' +
    'data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required></div>';
}
```

The code above generates...

```html
<div id="inputDiv" class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">1</span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for FREQUENCY" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName1" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
  <div class="input-group bottom15"><span class="input-group-addon">2</span><input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="paramName" value="DAYS"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the description for DAYS" name="paramDescriptions" id="paramName2" data-validation-message="The description must be between 2 and 25 characters. No special characters allowed."
      data-validation="[L>=2, L<=25, MIXED]" required=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem: http://prntscr.com/iov9bz

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson That's the worst non-sense I've read on SO for months.

Comment: You might want to try `let i = 0;` instead of  `var i = 0;`

Comment: wouldn't the inputs need a unique name too?  How is the error message appended?

Comment: I don't know but the names need to  be the same so I can send the array to the backend.

Comment: @user9463015 Could you provide the JavaScript part as well?

Comment: that's the javascript. Just add a random array called result to test

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery form Validation](http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/) looks for elements using this part of the code:

```
node.find('input:not([type="submit"]), select, textarea')
```

so every `input` field in your example will be checked. However, the error is registered for the field's name attribute:

```
var inputName = $(input).attr('name')

// ...

registerError(inputName, error[0].replace('$', inputShortName).replace('%', error[1]));
```

That's the reason you see error message for both fields.

A simple change of the field's name value to a unique value will fix this issue.